firebase function - on region return internal error
I have predefined X num of functions, defined on the Firebase emulator in the function folder. One of them:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");


const REGION = "europe-west3";
const serviceAccount = require("./eko-volonter-dev-firebase-adminsdk.json");
const { FieldValue } = require("@google-cloud/firestore");


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
const db = admin.firestore();
const fcm = admin.messaging();
const storage = admin.storage();

exports.updateUserInCollection = functions
  .region(REGION)
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    ....
  });


package.json for functions:
...
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-ts": "^1.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
...

When trying to run:
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';

import '../constants/strings.dart';

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> updateUserInCollection({
  required Map<String, dynamic> data,
}) async {
  final callable = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: Strings.ffRegion) // region same as emulator, string exists
      .httpsCallable(Strings.ffUpdateUserInCollection); // fun name, string exists
  final res = await callable.call<Map<String, dynamic>>(data);
  return res.data;
}

That function returns:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] INTERNAL

#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>


So, if the region does not exist, func works, but must FirebaseFunctions reverse from instanceFor to instance.
ps. The emulator runs very well. Other all servicers works, just function makes problem.
